# Getting a single signed Windows driver which passes HLK and HCK tests

Tags: windows, hardware, drivers, driver-signing

We have a driver which passes the HLK and HCK tests. When we're ready to submit it to Microsoft we take the HCK results and merge them with the HLK results, sign it, and submit it to Microsoft. When we get the drivers back from Microsoft we get *two* drivers, one signed for win7 and the other signed for win10. We would like one driver, signed for both Windows 7 and Windows 10, so we don't have to worry about shipping different versions to our customers.

Are we merging our `.hckx` and HLK test results incorrectly? Is there something we can do in the portal to tell Microsoft that the drivers are bit-for-bit identical, and we only want one binary back from them?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue was?